# Facebook API to get the details of events posted by everyone as public

Tags: api, facebook

I am trying to get facebook API to give the below information of all the events which are public.

Event name,
Description,
Start date and time,
Location

I have tried using below API in Graph API Explorer. It is giving the response if I give the 'event id' of event created by me. But not all the events which are available publicly.

```
GET /v12.0/{event-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Is it like we dont have option to get the details of public events or we have any other API/option to get the public event details?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since [facebooks data restriction update](https://about.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/) it's no longer possible to get public events of pages because you need to have [page-public-metadata-access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference#page-public-metadata-access) for this page. Facebook says that you need the following:

- successful completion of the App Review process
- business verification
- admin role for the Page

If you want to get the information of you own pages you just need to give the pages_read_engagement permission and the pages_read_user_content permission.

I was thinking about using [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to scrape the data without api but the following link stopped me from doing this https://www.octoparse.com/blog/5-things-you-need-to-know-before-scraping-data-from-facebook.

Comment: Ok. But Facebook is suggesting to use Marketing APIs for this

Comment: The thing that is unclear about Facebook's documentation is how do you get access to PUBLIC events that are NOT related to a page?  IE:  Created by any user and made public.   I found that I cannot access events either using an endpoint, even though I could access the event from any browser without logging in.   Even if there is a permission to gain this access - why is there one?